# Can't link any framework using Carthage or CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, cocoapods, carthage

I've tried to add a few Icon-font projects to my Cocoa Touch Framework using both CocoaPods as well as Carthage, but keep getting `ld: framework not found SomeIconFont`

Things I've tried to do:

- Dragged and dropped latest `.framework` into *Linked Framework and Libraries*
- Have tried to add a *Copy Files* with destination *Frameworks* in Build Phases before *Link Binary with Libraries* phase
- Have added the `carthage copy-frameworks` *Run Script* for the framework with `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/SomeIconFont.framework`
- Have set *Build Active Architecture Only* to *Yes* at both, the Project level as well as the target
- Architecture for both is *Standard*
- Have set *Framework Search Paths* for both, Project as well as Target to `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS` respectively
- Have tried Cleaning, resetting *DerivedData*

My last options are animal-sacrifice and an underwater hand-stand, but of course, they're only second to reinstalling Xcode and its few GB again. I'm only posting this question because quite honestly, completely beaten by this problem for the last 48 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of 2 gruelling days (what I've saved you from!), I've finally managed to fix this:

*Underneath* **Framework Search Paths**, you shall see **Debug** and **Release**, and both house a **Any Architecture | Any SDK**.

Simply setting **Any Architecture | Any SDK** to `$(inherited)` fixed this issue for me. Of course, this will *not* work if you haven't set the top-level to `$(SRCROOT)/...` as shown in the OP, as it will only mimic the parent element's value!

Why this is *not* a duplicate of one of the hundred other questions/blogs you'll find online: nearly *all* relevant posts as of writing this are for an *Application*, and not a *Dynamic Library/Cocoa Touch Framework*

Comment: Is this the default setting?

Comment: @DanRosenstark Nope! The only place I saw `$(inherited)` before was in the CocoaPods warning, asking you to add it at the top-level for _Framework Search Paths_, but for some reason it does _not_ cascade at least on the current Xcode version

Comment: Now I remember. I'd been through this before. Unfortunately my notes aren't a great help ;)

http://dr2050.com/automatic-images/__inherited_.png